# Percentage of returning visitors in google data studio

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

Here what I want is get the number of returning visitor in percentage in scorecard.What I tried is tried creating calculating filed but didn't able to succeed

What I tried is applied the usertype = "returning visitor" filter but it shows only number and I want percentage.

Expected result is %returning visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this method isn't entirely accurate. GA double counts a user if they are both a returning user and new user if they complete more than 1 session within the time period that you have listed.

My work around is to blend a data source with itself: 1 with a Google segment for returning users, 1 without.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the calculated field should use these two metrics:

ga:users (Users): total number of users
ga:newUsers (New Users): total number of new users

ga:newUsers/ga:users will give you the percentage of new users, the rest would be return. So just subtract the % from 1. Like so

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Returning visitor in data studio
Showing the total number of returning visitors via the Scorecard

There is 2 ways to make it
1
Step 1
usertype = "returning visitor"  pie chart or in table
Just make a new Pie chart or table then add to demensions Usertype

Step 2:
Add a new scoreboard
Make a filter for scoreboard just to show Returning of New visitors.

Done !!  Showing the total number of returning visitors via the Scorecard.

Step 3 showing as a %
Add a new scoreboard without any filter and just show session.
Click at Scoreboard which shows Returning or New visitors. Click also in sametime at the scoreboard which shows session.. then right click on the mouse, choise the Merge data options.
Data studio makes automaticly percentage of both data. You get it!!!!

Second Way
You'll need to create a segment for in Google Analytics to use in Data Studio
Make a segment for returning visitors in Google Analytics.
Add a new scoreboard in data studio, choose just made segment.  You will see the total Returning visitors in scoreboard.

follow step 2 and 3 ..

Good luck..